# grid display not displaying correctly

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, css-grid, anchor

I'm having trouble getting my grid to display the way i want and i can't see what i've done wrong. Please take a look at this for me.

It was displaying correctly when i was using background-image url() in css but i needed to use image tags because they need to be hyperlinks and i'm pretty sure this was the only way. When i use img tags the pictures were now displaying in their full size and i couldnt get them back to the right scale. and when i wrapped them in anchor tags they stopped displaying in the correct order.

Here's my code

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.8rem;

}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
}


header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  padding-right: 5%;
}



header h1 {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 1px;
  min-width: 20%;
  color: yellow;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: underline darkblue;
  width: 60%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

nav li {
  display: inline;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding-left: 8%;
  color: yellow;



}

.heroBanner {
  background-image: url("../images/02-hero-bg.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;

}

#page-section {
  width: 100%;
}

#title {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  right: 10%;
  background-color: blue;
  color: yellow;
}

/* Put my about stuff here */


#about {
  display: flex;
  padding: 3%;

}

#about p {
  align-items: stretch;
  color: yellow;
}

#about-1 {
  width: 20%;
  border-right: solid 8px darkblue;
}

#about-2 {
  width: 80%;
  padding-left: 3%;
  background-image: url(/my-work/images/Portfolio-avatar.png);
  background-size:contain;
  background-position: center;

}

#work {
  height: 1200px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 3%;
}

#work-1 {
  width: 20%;
  border-right: solid 8px darkblue;

}

#work-2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 
  'one one'
  'two three'
  'four five'
}
.pics {
  position: relative;
}

.pic-title {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15%;
  background-color: blue;
  color: yellow;
}

#big {
  grid-area: one;
  object-fit: contain;
  margin: 10px;
  border: solid 4px darkblue;
}

#pic1 {
  grid-area: two;
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 10px;
  border: solid 4px darkblue;
}

#pic2 {
  grid-area: three;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin: 10px;
  border: solid 4px darkblue;
}

#pic3 {
  grid-area: four;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin: 10px;
  border: solid 4px darkblue;
}

#pic4 {
  grid-area: five;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin: 10px;
  border: solid 4px darkblue;
}

#picture1, #picture2, #picture3, #picture4, #picture5 {
  object-fit: cover;
}

#contact {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  padding: 3%;
}

#work-2 {
  width: 75%;
}

#contact-1 {
  width: 20%;
  border-right: solid 8px darkblue;
}

#contact-2 {
  width: 80%;
}

#contact-2 ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: underline darkblue;
  width: 80%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-gb">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Lorenzo Francis-Walker // Junior Web Developer</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>


  <!-- main logo / nav -->
  <header>
    <h1>Lorenzo Francis-Walker</h1>
    <nav>
      <li><a href="#about-1">About me</a></li>
      <li><a href="#work-1">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact-1">Contact Me</a></li>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <!-- hero banner -->
  <section class="heroBanner">
    <h2 id="title">Room4Renzo</h2>
  </section>

  <main class="page-wrapper">
    <!-- about me -->
    <section class="page-section" id="about">
      <div id="about-1">
        <h2>About Me</h2>
      </div>
      <div id="about-2">
        <p>My love for computers comes from a fairly young age and is greater than my current experience. I was given an
          old PC by a friend that soon stopped working. He had another one that worked but soon after giving that to me
          , it too stopped working. I found a pdf of how to build computers for dummies on my phone and used what i had
          learned to combine the two PC's parts into one case, and it worked. I had always been interested in technology
          but this is where my love for understanding computers and how they work. Once you learn about different types
          of hardware theres not many places to go. ie networking, coding, etc. fortunately for me, the depth of the
          limited options are vast, so there is alot left for me to learn and I never want my journey to end.</p>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- portfolio container -->
    <section class="page-section" id="work">

      <div id="work-1">
        <h2>Work</h2>
      </div>
      <div id="work-2">

        <a href="" target="_blank">
          <div id="big" class="pics">
            <img src="./images/02-run-buddy.jpg" id="picture1" alt="" class="grid-column-span-2">
            <div class="pic-title">
              <h2>Run Buddy</h2>
              <p>Languages Used</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>

        <a href="" target="_blank">
          <div id="pic1" class="pics">
            <img src="./images/02-portfolio-1.jpg" id="picture2" alt="">
            <div class="pic-title">
              <h2>LED Wall</h2>
              <p>Languages Used</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>

        <a href="" target="_blank">
          <div id="pic2" class="pics">
            <img src="./images/02-portfolio-2.jpg" id="picture3" alt="">
            <div class="pic-title">
              <h2>Calculator</h2>
              <p>Languages Used</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>

        <a href="" target="_blank">
          <div id="pic3" class="pics">
            <img src="./images/02-portfolio-3.jpg" id="picture4" alt="">
            <div class="pic-title">
              <h2>Pastel Puzzels</h2>
              <p>Languages Used</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>

        <a href="" target="_blank">
          <div id="pic4" class="pics">
            <img src="./images/02-portfolio-4.jpg" id="picture5" alt="">
            <div class="pic-title">
              <h2>Surf Report</h2>
              <p>Languages Used</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

    </section>

    <!-- contact -->
    <section class="page-section contact" id="contact">
      <div id="contact-1">
        <h2>Contact Me</h2>
      </div>
      <div id="contact-2">
        <ul>
          <li>Email: Lorenzo.afw@gmail.com</li>
          <li>Github: Room4Renzo </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </section>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

i tried manually resizing, using object-fit as i saw in another answer, i tried different amount of columns for the grid, same for the rows. i can;t find where my mistake is. appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried removing the ids (which contain the grid area) from the divs and adding them to the anchor tags?

Comment: Please edit your question and add a snippet which we can use to play around with your problem. As it stands, we need to paste your html, css somewhere and use some ad hoc images in order to test.

Comment: Grid items have to be direct children of the grid container. A div container can also be a grid item but if your images are the item you are trying to place, it must be referenced as a direct child of the element whose grid area you have assigned to it. Personally, I would place all the images inside one grid container.

Comment: ninadepina, I haven't tried moving the id's yet but i will see what happens. Lajos Arpad, I don't actually know how to do that but i will try and edit the question. Dave Pritlove, I will put all of the images with their h2 and p titles as they have to be displayed together. Thanks guys for your suggestions.

Comment: Your code references local images, which of course are not available when the snippet runs. If you edit your snippet to reference images which are available on the internet (use Google Image Search to find some), then we will be able to see the problem.